# How to display results step by step in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-blade

I read a Students table in a controller and then return to a view ['students' => $students].
In the view I display information (after a treatment) for each student.
In fact the page display when the loop is finished but I would like to display the results one after the other in my loop to show the progress and not all at once !
I tried ajax but the process is slower because the class controller is initialized on each call.

```
<?php
$Ctrl = new App\Http\Controllers\StudentsController();
$Ctrl->InitInfos();  // read tables and parameters and takes 1 second
?>

@foreach ($students as $student)
    <?php
    $informations = $Ctrl->getInfo($student);  // this takes few seconds
    echo $informations . '<br>';
    ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: why dont you give the view $students then loop on it ?

Comment: The above code is in the view.